# How to create loader, when navigating from one page to another page not working

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, loader

I am working in a project, and i need a loader, when we navigate one page to another page loader will show and when fully loaded the page loader should hide, It is working when i navigating the page it is working but not hiding, when page finish loading.

I have added a div in header and a css class and jquery to hide the div.
Added in header

```
<div class="loader">  </div>

Added in footer 
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on("load", function (e) {
            $(".loader").fadeout("slow"); 

        })
</script>

Added css
.loader{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;background:url(../images/loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #fff;opacity:.80;
}
```

Its continuously showing while navigating to page i want this to hide when page loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is a small mistake you did, that`s the reason is continuously showing the the loader.

In fadeout should be "fadeOut"

Here is the answer with working snippet.

```js
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow"); 

        })
```

```css
.loader{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;background:url(https://icon-library.net/images/loading-icon-animated-gif/loading-icon-animated-gif-19.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat #fff;opacity:.80;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">  </div>

<a href="#">Home</a>

<a href="#">About</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, ya its working for me. sorry for small mistake.